# HTMLAgilityPack using my own tags

Tags: c#, html-agility-pack

I need to parse few html elements to list using html agility pack and remove them from document. I wrote following code:

```
HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlDocument();
doc.Load(tempFileHTML);
doc.OptionSupportOptionalEndTags = true;
doc.OptionWriteEmptyNodes = true;

List<HtmlNode> tagResolver = doc.DocumentNode.Descendants("link").ToList();
for (int i = 0; i < tagResolver.Count; i++)
{
    elements.Add(tagResolver[i].OuterHtml);
    tagResolver[i].Remove();
}

doc.Save(tempFileHTML, Encoding.GetEncoding(HTMLtoPDF.DefaultEncoding));
```

The problem is that my start html file looks like this:

```
<table>
    <LOOP>
        <tr>
            <td>{CODE}</td>
        </tr>
    </LOOP>
</table>
```

and after doc.Save() this file looks like this:

```
<table>
    <loop>
    </loop>
        <tr>
            <td>{CODE}</td>
        </tr>
</table>
```

Is there any way to save this document correctly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is some specific logic in the agility pack to enforce a correct structure. This code specifically targets `li`, `ul`, `table`, `tr` etc. so you might be hitting this. See the [`HtmlDocument.GetResetters`](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#Release/1_4_0/HtmlAgilityPack/HtmlDocument.cs) method. Turning off `OptionFixNestedTags` using `doc.OptionFixNestedTags = false`, should circumvent that behavior.

You should register your tag(s) using `HtmlNode.ElementsFlags.Add` from the top of my head the right syntax is:

```
HtmlNode.ElementsFlags.Add("LOOP",  HtmlElementFlag.Empty | HtmlElementFlag.Closed);
```

That way you can define how you expect the HtmlAgilityPack to parse your markers.

Also: There is a [`MixedCodeDocument`](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#Release/1_4_0/HtmlAgilityPack/MixedCodeDocument.cs) class which you can use as well, which requires you to specify a token for your own tags, that way you could use `<%loop%>` and it might provide an escape for you. You can specify the `TokenStart` and `TokenEnd` on the document before parsing.

Comment: Setting OptionFixNestedTags to false works perfectly. Thanks!